# How to read from an external console application?

Tags: delphi

I have a console application that I didn't write. Is there some easy way to read from it?
I need to have the input still on the console window, but read what's being displayed.

I care not whether the output displays to the console or not, so long as the input still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Console Application Runner Classes](http://www.delphidabbler.com/software/consoleapp/main?mid=3.2) are excellent to control the console application processes and to redirect input and output where required.

Comment: This looks promising, i'll check it out.  The only problem I've had in the past with using an fstream for the input is that I can't emulate an enter keypress.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project that is doing the same thing. I have a console application written in VB.Net and I run and capture it's output using my Delphi application. I have successfully achieved this by following this [tutorial](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_2.htm) by Zarko Gajic.

Comment: The code at that site is identical to the code in Ervins's answer. It doesn't handle console input, and it only reads output after the child terminates.