# embedded console applications in Delphi

Tags: delphi, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read from an external console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526994/how-to-read-from-an-external-console-application)

I have a third party console application

I want to execute it at run time form a delphi application.

on the execution

the console applications window must be hidden.and all the messages of the console application must be printed in a control of my application (Text box , memo etc)

and also using the control user must be able to input text.

Can anyone help me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526994/how-to-read-from-an-external-console-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212176/delphi-6-read-console-apps-output-while-running/1212378#1212378) one.

Zarko wrote about this on [Delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/b/2007/04/21/capture-the-output-of-a-console-mode-application-from-delphi.htm).

This is a common requirement, for example, in IDEs and build tools, or apps which spawn external command line tools to do version control, for example.

To make the answer two-way, as you ask for it to be, is very complex, and I am not aware of anybody who has implemented a "command shell" or "terminal mode" completely in delphi.

I ported Zlatko's code to Delphi XE (also works in 2010) [here](http://cid-f5bb35ae00415bc7.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/uZpRunConsoleApp.zip).

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, please comment on why this could be improved?

Answer (score 4):

This will allow you to run and receive info back from a console (DOS-type) application into a TRichEdit. It doesn't allow you to input text once the app is running, but maybe it'll give you a starting point. (The original code is from a newsgroup post written by Dr. Peter Below of TeamB.)

```
procedure TFMainForm.RunDosInMemo(const App: String; AMemo: TRichEdit);
const
  ReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  Security : TSecurityAttributes;
  StdInPipeR, StdInPipeW : THandle;
  StdOutPipeR, StdOutPipeW : THandle;
  StartInfo : TStartUpInfo;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  Buffer : PByte;
  BytesAvailable, BytesRead : DWord;
  sDosApp: String;
  sData: RawByteString;
begin
  sDosApp := DosApp;
  UniqueString(sDosApp);

  with Security do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
    bInheritHandle := True;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;

  if CreatePipe(StdInPipeR, StdInPipeW, @Security, 0) then
  try

    SetHandleInformation(StdInPipeW, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    if CreatePipe(StdOutPipeR, StdOutPipeW, @Security, 0) then
    try
      SetHandleInformation(StdOutPipeR, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
      GetMem(Buffer, ReadBuffer);
      try
        ZeroMemory(@StartInfo, SizeOf(StartInfo));
        StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartInfo);
        StartInfo.hStdOutput := StdOutPipeW;
        StartInfo.hStdInput := StdInPipeR;
        StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

        if CreateProcess(nil, 
                         PChar(sDosApp), 
                         nil, 
                         nil, 
                         True, 
                         NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 
                         nil, 
                         nil, 
                         StartInfo, 
                         ProcessInfo) then
          try
            while WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 500) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT do
              Application.ProcessMessages;
            while PeekNamedPipe(StdOutPipeR, nil, 0, nil, BytesAvailable, nil) do 
            begin
              if BytesAvailable < 1 then 
                Break;
              if BytesAvailable > ReadBuffer then 
                BytesAvailable := ReadBuffer;
              if not ReadFile(StdOutPipeR, 
                              Buffer[0], 
                              BytesAvailable, 
                              BytesRead, 
                              nil) then 
                Break;
              SetString(sData, PAnsiChar(Buffer), BytesRead);
              // assign an appropriate codepage for the output data:
              // 0 for default Ansi, 1252 or 20157 for ASCII, 1200 for 
              // Unicode, etc...
              SetCodePage(sData, ...);
              // this is faster and more efficient than reading/writing the 
              // Text property directly...
              AMemo.SelStart := AMemo.GetTextLen;
              AMemo.SelLength := 0;
              AMemo.SelText := sData;
            end;
          finally
            CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
            CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
          end;
      finally
        FreeMem(Buffer);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(StdOutPipeR);
      CloseHandle(StdOutPipeW);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdInPipeR);
    CloseHandle(StdInPipeW);
  end;
end;
```